Is there a way to create a Perforce Shelve CL that changes the directory to a symbolic link?
Imagine you have a directory in your P4 repo, for example:

//SOME/P4/PATH/scripts/qemu/

You want to replace this directory with a symlink:

//SOME/P4/PATH/scripts/qemu -> //SOME/P4/PATH/scripts/qemu.orig

Is there a way to create a shelve for this?

Have you tried deleting the directory and adding a symlink in its place?  Once you've opened the files they should shelve just like any other pending changes.  If you're having trouble either opening or shelving the files, please include whatever error messages you're getting.

Yes, I've tried this method. Using the proposed approach, it is possible to create a Shelve CL. However, it is not possible to unshelve such a CL due to an error regarding an existing directory.

The error during unshelve operation is following: "symlink: /P4/docs/debugging: File exists".

That sounds like a bug with the unshelve command that should be reported to Perforce support.  As a workaround I bet that if you manually delete the local folder it'll work.

It is possible to create such a Shelve CL.
To do this, it is necessary to:

Remove ("Mark for delete"):

//SOME/P4/PATH/scripts/qemu


Create a symlink with the same name.
Add this new symlink to the Shelve CL ("Mark for Add...").
"Shelve..." the removed and newly added files/symlink.

However, an error will occur when unshelving this Shelve CL:

In other words, Perforce is somewhat limited in this regard.
